# How to increase icon size of tabs in TabLayout

Tags: android

I am trying to increase icon size of tabs in my app. Icon sizes are fixed tried out many ways but nothing is working, finally tried the following but no change in size.Please if any one can tell me the right way I will be glad.Thanks in advance.

Here is my code,

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.my1));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.feed_s));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.add_ds1));
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.history_ds));
tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

**style.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">50dp</item>
</style>
```

**tablayout.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ActionBar"/>
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Hi I faced the same problem before and this is the best solution I could find:

You should use (setCustomView), first of all make a new layout file
lets name it (customtab.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then and for each tab do this: (use the same layout .xml)

```
View view1 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtab, null);
view1.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my1);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view1));


View view2 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtab, null);
view2.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my2);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view2));


View view3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtab, null);
view3.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my3);
tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view3));

...
```

OR 
in a similar way

```
public static final int[] tabIcon = {R.drawable.icon_one, R.drawable.icon_two, R.drawable.icon_three};

private void setCustomTabs() {

    for (int i = 0; i < tabIcon.length; i++) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.customtab,null);
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
        view.findViewById(R.id.icon).setBackgroundResource(tabIcon[i]);
        if(tab!=null) tab.setCustomView(view);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It was the best solution :)

Comment: But do i need to create different view for each tab icon

Comment: I cannot set tab text using this approach

Comment: @NeonWarge you can if you add a text view

Comment: @GalebNassri exactly what I did. Thanks!

Comment: In my case the icon ImageView could not be fetched by the framework until I specified the ID as follow: `android:id="@android:id/icon"` Possibly because I'm working on a fairly large code base that had its own definition of `id/icon`. Consider updating your solution accordingly.

Comment: This solution is good and misleading. The author creates new tabs, while better is to use existing (not adding 3 to existing 3 tabs). See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47495989/2914140.

Comment: God, how is this the correct answer! The id of the ImageView has to be android:id="@android:id/icon" to make this work.

Answer (score 22):

As stated in the documentation, you can create a new layout with an `ImageView` with `android:id="@android:id/icon"` and set it as the custom view for the tab. The TabLayout will automatically place the icon in the inner ImageView with `android:id/icon`

Then in you code you can call the `setIcon(R.drawable.yourIcon)` while you create the tab.

Then you can apply you custom layout within a for loop :

```
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.searchpin));
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.discussionpin));
mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.userpin));

for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
    TabLayout.Tab tab = mTabLayout.getTabAt(i);
    if (tab != null) tab.setCustomView(R.layout.view_home_tab);
}
```

Here is the xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@android:id/icon"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/tab_icon_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_icon_size"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Worked for me. Additionally if you want to use a selector to represent different states you need to set the initial selected state of your custom view.      tab.getCustomView().setSelected(tab.isSelected());

Comment: what is tab_icon_size?

Comment: This is just a [dimension resource](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicSyncAdapter/res/values/dimen.html) created in the values/dimens.xml file.

Comment: But you can use any value you want

Comment: This will take the whole tab. What if we have an icon with text and we don't want the text to disappear?

Answer (score 5):

No need to take any xml view . Create imageview runtime and add image as view :)

```
    for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setImageResource(drawableImage);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(imageView);
    }
```

Happy codding

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change inside all screens i mean full application then you can try this:
Create file inside layout folder named: **design_layout_tab_icon.xml**
and paste below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:id="@android:id/icon"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
```

Do not change the id leave it and on your screen where tab bar is set some height that you want and viola!!!
It will apply to all places

Answer (score 0):

This is a custom **TabLayout** it can help a lot!

```
public class TabView extends TabLayout {

public TabView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public TabView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public TabView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    int padding = 10;

    int[] icons = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_tel, R.drawable.ic_speaker, R.drawable.ic_camera, R.drawable.ic_home};

    for (int i = 0; i < icons.length; i++) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        imageView.setImageResource(icons[i]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        if (i==3){
            addTab(newTab().setCustomView(imageView), i , true);
        } else {
            addTab(newTab().setCustomView(imageView), i);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    View view5 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_icon, null);
    view5.findViewById(R.id.iconImg).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ambulance);
    icon_text=(TextView)view5.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
    icon_text.setText("Blood Bank");
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(view5));

    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]).setCustomView(view1);
```