# Xamarin.Forms: Change Icon & Text size in TabbedPage tabs

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I am developing Tabs using TabbedPage in `xaml`. The default tabs **Icons & Text size is big** so I need to reduce the size of Icons & Text. Below is my `main.xaml` code Where I am setting icons.

```
<TabbedPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"              
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedApp">
    <local:DairyTabs Icon="dairy" HeightRequest="10" WidthRequest="10" ></local:DairyTabs>
    <local:Mykid Icon="kid" ></local:Mykid>
    <local:Event Icon="about"></local:Event>    
</TabbedPage>
```

This is First page of tabs where I am giving Title of tab as `Title="Dairy"`

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"              
             Title="Dairy"> 
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Button x:Name="btnDemo" Text="Go for 2nd page"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

See the below Screenshot where you can see icons and tab text.

[image]

Comment: see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194140/is-there-a-way-to-stop-longer-xamarin-shell-tab-titles-being-truncated/62656858#62656858

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some effort i get it work for android using `TabbedPageRenderer`. Created custom layout with `ImageView` & `TetxtView` below **Custom_tab_layou.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="41dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="18dp"
        android:layout_height="18dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="hello"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="11dp"
        android:textColor="#00FF6F" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Created `MyTabbedPageRenderer` class

```
    public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        private Dictionary<Int32, Int32> icons = new Dictionary<Int32, Int32>();
        bool setup;
        ViewPager pager;
        TabLayout layout;
        public MyTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void SetTabIcon(TabLayout.Tab tab, FileImageSource icon)
        {
            base.SetTabIcon(tab, icon);
            tab.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.Custom_tab_layou);

            var imageview = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.icon);
            var tv = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv);

            tv.SetText(tab.Text, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            imageview.SetBackgroundDrawable(tab.Icon);

            ColorStateList colors2 = null;

            if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
                colors2 = Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab, Forms.Context.Theme);
            else
                colors2 = Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab);
            tv.SetTextColor(colors2);
        }

        //this is for changing text color of select tab
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (setup)
                return;
            if (e.PropertyName == "Renderer")
            {
                pager = (ViewPager)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(0);
                layout = (TabLayout)ViewGroup.GetChildAt(1);
                setup = true;
                ColorStateList colors = null;

                if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 23)
                    colors = Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab, Forms.Context.Theme);
                else
                    colors = Resources.GetColorStateList(Resource.Color.icon_tab);

                for (int i = 0; i < layout.TabCount; i++)
                {
                    var tab = layout.GetTabAt(i);
                    var icon = tab.Icon;

                    Android.Views.View view = GetChildAt(i);
                    if (view is TabLayout) layout = (TabLayout)view;

                    if (icon != null)
                    {
                        icon = Android.Support.V4.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableCompat.Wrap(icon);
                        Android.Support.V4.Graphics.Drawable.DrawableCompat.SetTintList(icon, colors);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: [SetTabIcon is never called when using ToolbarPlacement.Bottom.](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3397#issuecomment-408350044)

Answer (score 5):

In your Android project's `Resources/values/style.xml` file, you can create a style:

```
<style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="android:textSize">8sp</item>
</style>
```

And then in your `Resources/layout/tabs.axml` file, you can use the style:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ... other attributes ...
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyTabTextStyle" />
```

As for the icon, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46465233/3183946

And by the way, I think "Dairy" should be "Diary" in your app

Comment: Yeah It should be "Diary" . My above code `main.xaml` is present in PCL of Xamarin.Forms project(common for Android, iOS, Windows). Are you saying not to use `main.xaml`?

Comment: No, you should use `main.xaml`. But to change the appearance of the tab text, you will have to change it in your Android project, specifically in the `tabs.axml` file. That is where the default styling for Android's native tab layout is set. Unfortunately you can't customize the tab's font size in your PCL project

Comment: Got it. And what about iOS? for that where do i need to write the code, because parallely I am executing app for both OS.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I really wanted to skip all the custom renderers... and many of the implementations seemed much more work than should be necessary. I was also implementing Font Awesome Icons which seemed pretty straight forward, but all of the examples I found applied the icons to labels and nothing with tabbed page. After some dinking around I finally compiled this which works great and removes the need of a renderer.

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IBMobile.Views"
         xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:FontAwesome"
         x:Class="IBMobile.Views.HomePage"
         Visual="Material">
<ContentPage.IconImageSource>
    <FontImageSource FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" Glyph="{x:Static local2:IconFont.Home}" />
</ContentPage.IconImageSource>...
```

**To answer the question of setting FontSize:**
Font Icon is a Font so it is set like any other. Example:

```
<Button x:Name="btnEmail" Clicked="BtnEmail_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding email}" FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" FontSize="Large" Text="{x:Static local2:IconFont.Envelope}"  Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="#007d5d" Margin="10" />
```

Comment: How do you set Icons size like this?

Comment: Was looking for an implementation of FA in IconImageSource.... Thanks.... BTW is there anyway of implementing this in <OnPlatform>???