# Make tabIndicator bigger than tabIcon

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-tabs

I want to make `tabIndicator` bigger than icon in my `Tabs` to make it looks like selected Button. Although I don't see any option for this in native `TabLayout`. I need some padding around icon so indicator will not "hug" icon borders - `ImageButton` with icon effect.

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_medium"
    app:tabIconTint="@color/tab_icon_tint"
    app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_primary"
    app:tabIndicatorGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="22dp"
    app:tabRippleColor="@null">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/tab_account_icon"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/tab_account_icon"/>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:icon="@drawable/tab_account_icon"/>

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

indicator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    android:shape="oval"
    android:useLevel="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/tab_primary" />
</shape>
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237896/how-to-increase-icon-size-of-tabs-in-tablayout

Comment: This doesnt work. With custom item it is stretching indicator to the full width of the tab so it looks like ellipse.